# How to keep track of programmatically added View elements?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

```
int counter = 0;

private void AddLayout()
{

    List<string> entryValues = new List<string>();
    
    List<StackLayout> stackList = new List<StackLayout>();

    StackLayout horizontalLayout = new StackLayout()
                            {
                                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                                Children =
                                {
                                    new Entry(),

                                    new Button
                                    {
                                        Text = "Add"
                                    },

                                    new Button
                                    {
                                        Text = "Remove"
                                    }
                                }
                            };

    container.Children.Add(horizontalLayout);

    stackList.Add(horizontalLayout);

    stackList[counter].Children.OfType<Entry>().FirstOrDefault().Unfocused += (o, ev) =>
    {
        entryValues.Add(horizontalLayout.Children.OfType<Entry>().FirstOrDefault().Text);
    };


    stackList[counter].Children.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault().Clicked += (o, ev) =>
    {
       container.Children.Add(horizontalLayout)
    };

    stackList[counter].Children.OfType<Button>().ElementAt(1).Clicked += (o, ev) =>
    {                            
        container.Children.Remove(horizontalLayout);

        counter--;
        stackList.RemoveAt(counter);
        entryValues.RemoveAt(counter);
    };

    counter++;
}
```

With the code above I try to give to the app's users the ability to add and remove as many `entry` `Views` they need. So far, so good.

Then my goal is to save the `Text` values of the `entries` to a database. For that purpose I use a list called `entryValues`. My question is when I click a certain "Remove" `button` how can I remove the corresponding value from the `entryValues` list (which is something that the current code does not achieve)?

Comment: I would make a dictionary, whose keys are the Entries, and whose values are the indices into entryValues.

Comment: I tested the code you provided, and the current Remove button directly deletes the entire StackLayout. You say: "when I click a certain "Remove" button how can I remove the corresponding value from the entryValues list". Do you want to also delete the corresponding Text value saved in the database?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT No. The value does get saved to the database when a button is clicked. Till that point there is nothing in the database. Also when the button gets clicked the page will close. In other words I just want to save to the database the values of the entries that still exist on the screen.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I'm not sure how the `Dictionary` approach should get implemented. I get this error: `System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout'`
All the `StackLayout` elements give the same key. Obviously the same goes for every `entry`.

Comment: Add to question the code you wrote for Dictionary (that does not work). You should be making a NEW UI element  (stacklayout, entry) each time you add one. Thus, those elements would not be the same.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve
I have found my mistake. I was using Add when trying to update the dictionary with the entry's value. Of course the correct code is `myDictionary[horizontalLayout] = horizontalLayout.Children.OfType<Entry>().FirstOrDefault().Text;`

Comment: @Costas Did changing the correct code solve your problem?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT Yes, it did. I will post the solution within the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that works with the help of a `Dictionary`:

```
private void AddLayout()
{

    Dictionary<StackLayout, string> stackLayoutDictionary = new Dictionary<StackLayout, string>();

    StackLayout horizontalLayout = new StackLayout()
                            {
                                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                                Children =
                                {
                                    new Entry(),

                                    new Button
                                    {
                                        Text = "Add"
                                    },

                                    new Button
                                    {
                                        Text = "Remove"
                                    }
                                }
                            };

    container.Children.Add(horizontalLayout);

    stackLayoutDictionary.Add(horizontalLayout, "");

    horizontalLayout.Children.OfType<Entry>().FirstOrDefault().Unfocused += (o, ev) =>
    {
        stackLayoutDictionary[horizontalLayout] = horizontalLayout.Children.OfType<Entry>().FirstOrDefault().Text;
    };


    horizontalLayout.Children.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault().Clicked += (o, ev) =>
    {
       container.Children.Add(horizontalLayout);
    };

    horizontalLayout.Children.OfType<Button>().ElementAt(1).Clicked += (o, ev) =>
    {                            
        container.Children.Remove(horizontalLayout);

        stackLayoutDictionary.Remove(horizontalLayout);
    };
}
```